# Numpy array minmax normalization python

Tags: python, numpy, normalization

I am new to python and here is my code

```
x = np.array(x)
mins = np.min(x, axis=0)
maxs = np.max(x, axis=0)
```

How can I normalize all values in each column? Now I have min and max values.
i is for rows and j is for columns

```
output[i, j] = (x[i,j] − mins[j]) / (maxs[j] - mins[j])
```

This should work, but my problem is to gen an output. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I need to normalize all columns, not only one. And how to cope with nans?

Comment: convert to a DataFrame and repeat the process.

Comment: Sometimes there can be a division by zero. I checked whether denominator is null. Thank you all!